# linear algebra with parabola

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A(3,22), B(2,12), and C(-4,-6) be three points on the plane. Find the equation of the parabola y=(a0)+(a1)x+(a2)x^2 that passes through these three points.

Prove that for any three points A(x1,y1),B(x2,y2), and C(x3,y3) there exist a unique parabola that passes through them if and only if their abscissae are distinct.

So, by making a matrix, I could find out a0,a1, and a2. 
a0=-2, a1=5 a2=1

Then how can i prove in general case?

Comment: Do you know Van der Monde determinant.

Comment: Van der Monde determinant?

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

You prove that the determinant of the system is not zero

$$a_0+a_1x_1+a_2x_1^2=y_1$$

$$a_0+a_1x_2+a_2x_2^2=y_2$$

$$a_0+a_1x_3+a_2x_3^2=y_3$$

to find $a_0,a_1$ and $a_2$.

Comment: I calculated the matrix with the value a0=-2, a1=5, a2=1, then i get that the determinant of the matrix is zero. am i doing something wrong??

Comment: The first line of the determinant is $1.  x_1.  x_1^2$.

Comment: ah, I calculated the determinant of matrix, and it comes to be           
   X2x3(x3-x2)+x1x2(x2-x1)+x1x3(x1-x3). and since the points are distinct, it can't be zero, so it has a unique solution! am i right?

Comment: @JJJ it is $(x_2-x_1)(x_3-x_1)(x_3-x_2$) $ not zero. there is a unique solution.